# How do I get a box shadow to appear under different elements

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get a css box shadow from a circular to appear underneath a nav bar that appears under the image itself. At the moment I can get the image to create a shadow that appears on top of the nav bar but I want it to appear that it is all one object.

I've tried using :before on the class ".logo" and putting the shadow at a different z-index but it just makes the shadow disappear. I'm rather new to web stuff (as well as stack overflow) so any help will be appreciated.

This is the css I'm using and the issue is with the logo class

```
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #DCDCDC;
    background-color: #222035;
    margin: 0px;
}
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
.logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.logo:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2vh 5vh #000000;
}
.topnav {
    box-shadow: 0px 2vh 5vh #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
    background-color: #222035;
}
 
header {
    padding: 170px;
}
```

And the rest of the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-UK">
    <head>
        <title>WOW</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <nav class="topnav">
        <img class = "logo" src="icon.png"></nav>
        
    </body>
```

Comment: Would you be able to share a codepen link?

Comment: https://codepen.io/FlippyFishy/pen/bGNYLrb is this what you mean?

Comment: maybe the image should be just a `block` element with `margin: auto` https://codepen.io/toniweb/pen/rNwqRXN

Comment: that hasn't really done what I want. I still want the image to be where it is, I just need the shadow to be below the nav bar instead of ontop of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use filter:  `filter:drop-shadow(0px 2vh 5vh #000000);` on the `nav` itself instead a `box-shadow`.

`drop-shadow()` follows the shape of the container while `box-shadow` follows the original shape of the container (rectangle).

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()

example

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #DCDCDC;
  background-color: #222035;
  margin: 0px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.topnav {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 5px #fff);/* make it obvious for the demo */
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: #222035;
}

header {
  padding: 170px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="topnav">
  <img class="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/1bkLMQt/Suit-Yourself-logo-2.png">
</nav>
```